# Can I legally purchase ammunation with a mental health issue in north carolina?

Tags: north-carolina

Can I legally purchase ammunition with a mental health hospitalization in north Carolina?

I was hospitalized recently can I legally purchase ammo in North Carolina?

Comment: Was the hospital a court ordered one or voluntarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

North Carolina does not regulate ammunition sales, other than teflon-coated bullets. Federal law does however and under [18 USC 922(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/922)

> It shall be unlawful for any person to sell or otherwise dispose of
>   any firearm or ammunition to any person knowing or having reasonable
>   cause to believe that such person... (4) has been adjudicated as a
>   mental defective or has been committed to any mental institution

On a related theme, NC law ([G.S. 14-404(c)(4)](https://www4.ncleg.net/enactedlegislation/statutes/html/bysection/chapter_14/gs_14-404.html)) also prohibits issuing a firearms permit to

> One who has been adjudicated mentally incompetent or has been
>   committed to any mental institution.

Both laws refer to being *committed* to a mental institution, which is a legal process, thus simply being a resident in a hospital with mental issues does not qualify.